# Assign values to an array inside a function

Tags: php, arrays

```
$another_array = array();

$array = array(5 => 1, 12 => 2);
make_another_array($array);
print_r($another_array);

function make_another_array(array $array) {

    foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
       $another_array[$key] = $value;

    }
}
```

I'm adding values to `$another_array` inside a function, but when I print the`$another_array` after calling the function, its giving a blank array.

Why is it so ? How to correctly assign values to `$another_array` and print outside the function here so that its not blank ?

Comment: You're not returning the result of the function. The array you assign inside the function has nothing to do with the array you declared outside the function. Hence, to get anything from the function, you'll have to return whatever you want from that function, either with `return`, `echo`, `print_r` or similar. Also, there is no reason to create the variable outside the function, it won't be available inside the function, unless you pass it to the function via an option on calling the function, or make it global within the funciton.

Comment: Were any of the 4 given answers useful? if so, upvote. If it resolved, mark it. Don't leave a question hanging.

Answer (score 2):

You're not capturing or returning the data:

```
function make_another_array(array $array) {
  foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
    $another_array[$key] = $value;
  }

  return $another_array; // return here
}

$array = array(5 => 1, 12 => 2);
$another_array = make_another_array($array); // capture the returned value
print_r($another_array);
```

Secondly, you might just want to use this instead:

```
$another_array = array_values($array);
```

---

As by comment below, there is the pass by reference method:

```
function update_array(array &$array) {
  $array[3] = 12;
}
update_array($array);
print_r($array);
```

And finally, the not preferred method..

```
function update_array(array $a) {
  global $another_array;

  foreach($a as $key => $value){
    $another_array[$key] => $value;
  }
}

// or just array_merge
// $array = array_merge($array, $another_array);
```

Comment: How can I make $another_array as global so that I can use it without returning ?

Comment: I would see that as "bad practice" as it quickly pollutes the scope. There are other methods available.

Comment: ok. I was asking in case I need to return more than one value from the function, I should be aware of a different way which I got from danchik's answer below. Just for knowledge. Thank you.

Comment: If you need to return more then one value you should consider learning about classes \ objects.

Answer (score 1):

You have to return the another_array inside the function:
The variables declared inside a function are local-only, and the variables declared outside aren't accessible.

```
$array = array(5 => 1, 12 => 2);
$another_array = make_another_array($array);
print_r($another_array);

function make_another_array(array $array) {

    $another_array = array();
    foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
       $another_array[$key] = $value;

    }
    return $another_array;
}
```

alternatively, you could also pass another array by reference:

```
$another_array = array();

$array = array(5 => 1, 12 => 2);
make_another_array($array, $another_array);
print_r($another_array);

function make_another_array(array $array, &$another_array) {

    foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
       $another_array[$key] = $value;

    }
}
```

or, you could set them inside the function using the global keyword (but I'd recommend using the other two solutions):

```
$another_array = array();
$array = array(5 => 1, 12 => 2);
make_another_array($array);
print_r($another_array);

function make_another_array(array $array) {

    global $another_array;
    foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
       $another_array[$key] = $value;

    }
}
```

and finally you could use the superglobal $GLOBALS, which is accessible in all scopes. (which is pretty the same as the sollution above)

```
$another_array = array();
$array = array(5 => 1, 12 => 2);
make_another_array($array);
print_r($another_array);

function make_another_array(array $array) {

    foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
        $GLOBALS['another_array'][$key] = $value;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure there is a reference to $another_array as global to point to the one outside of function, otherwise it is local only.

global $another_array; // put this at the beginning of the make_another_array( function.

```
$another_array = array();
$array = array(5 => 1, 12 => 2); 
make_another_array($array); 
print_r($another_array); 

function make_another_array(array $array) 
{ 
    global $another_array;

    foreach ($array as $key=>$value){

        $another_array[$key] = $value; 

    }


}
```

Comment: Why was this voted down?? Accepted answer DID NOT answer the question but provided a different solution.  Question was HOW TO properly assign to global variable from with in the function.  and you do it by declareing the global variable inside the function as `global $another_array;`

Comment: up voted. How to solve in this method ? Can you post the code here ?

Comment: `$another_array = array();

$array = array(5 => 1, 12 => 2);
make_another_array($array);
print_r($another_array);

function make_another_array(array $array) {
 global $another_array;  // <--- this line
    foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
       $another_array[$key] = $value;

    }
}`

Comment: just add the as the first line inside the function `global $another_array)`

Comment: just add the as the first line inside the function `global $another_array;` sorry with all the typos

Comment: yes. with little formatting, this works. Thanks. up voted the comment also.

Comment: And people who have down voted this answer, this answer is actually worth an up vote. Kindly cancel your down vote. The solution provides an alternative way.

Comment: i will always down vote the use of globals when not absolutely necessary.

Comment: @nogat and you are absolutely sure it is not 'absolutely necessary'?  Some functions are called by 'other' external functions that can not be modified, so modifying function definition may not be an option, thus you should always "Answer the Question Asked" as it states by this site.  Most of the time people will write a small snippet that represents the problem for the benefit of those that answer, not having to go through a large code.... your comment (to me) translates as "they have no idea what they are asking" and carries zero usefulness.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it [by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) like the following:

```
<?php
$another_array = array();
$array = array(5 => 1, 12 => 2);
function make_another_array($array, &$another_array) {

    foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
       $another_array[$key] = $value;

    }
    return $another_array;
}
make_another_array($array, $another_array);
print_r($another_array);
```

http://ideone.com/mAAeTp